# Total number of octahedral void(s) per atom in a cubic closed pack structure

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography

> The total number of octahedral void(s) per atom present in a cubic closed pack structure is
>
> (**a**) 1
> (**b**) 2
> (**c**) 3
> (**d**) 4

I answered with (**d**), but the key on internet says it is (**a**). Please clarify the dispute.

Comment: I assume you've seen diagrams?
http://www.chem.shef.ac.uk/chm131-1999/cha99ngs/intro4.gif & http://www.wou.edu/las/physci/ch412/ccp.jpg ... Seem to make the case for 1 gap pretty clear

  (http://www.chem.shef.ac.uk/chm131-1999/cha99ngs/aintro.html)

Answer (score 3):

Finally got it, it was a misunderstanding. I ignored to read the word ‘*per atom*’ in a hurry. So clearly the answer is 1.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just earned a self-learner badge (answer your own question and score +3).